# jQuery plugin - how/where to store data and how to share among methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Given this structure:

```
(function($) {

    var defaults = {
        dragDelay:    200, // tap/hold this long to activate dragging
        feedback:     'glow', // feedback to show drag mode (glow/pulsate)
        glowColor:    '#fff' // color of the glow if feedback==glow
    };

    var methods = {
        init:   function(options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                var $this = $(this);

                $this.bind('click', methods.doSomething);
            });
        },

        doSomething:    function(e) {
            //...
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlug = function(method) {
        if (methods[method])
            return methods[method].apply(this,
                Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method)
            return methods.init.apply(this,
                arguments.length > 0 ? arguments : [defaults]);
        else
            $.error("TypeError: Plugin 'myPlug' has no method '" + method +
                    "'");
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Is it preferable to use `$(this).data()` to store data, or `this.someVar = x`? Also, how do I get the init() method to share 'options' with the rest of the methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating some visual widget then you may create custom jQuery UI Widget (it has nice technique): 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide

But if not - then it's better to use `$(this).data(...)` to store some object's personal data.

How to get your `init()` method? You may also store it with `.data()` method.